# Как будет это записано на Си?

Tags: c

```
void readlong(int *a){
int i;
string s;
read(s);
a[0]=len(s);
for i=1..a[0]{
  a[a[0]-i+1]=ord(s[i])-48;
}
}

 void writelong(int *a){
   for i=a[0]..1{
  write(a[i]);
  }
 }
```

Вот мой вариант, но он что-то неправильно выводит цифры на экран

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
const int N = 1000;
void readlong(int *a) {
int i=0,k=0;
char s[N] = {0};
gets_s(s);
a[0] =strlen(s);
for (i = 1; i < a[0]; i++)
    a[a[0] - i + 1] = s[k] - '0';
k++;

}

void writelong(int *a) {
int i = 0;
for (i = a[0]; i >=1; i--)
    printf("%d", a[i]);
}

void main(void) {
int a[N] = { 0 };
readlong(a);
writelong(a);
_getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вы хотите получить? :)

Вот так - это оно или нет?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define N 1000

void readlong(int *a)
{
    int i;
    char s[N+1];
    gets_s(s,N+1);
    a[0] = strlen(s);
    for(i = 0; i < a[0]; i++)
        a[a[0] - i] = s[i] - '0';
}

void writelong(int *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = a[0]; i >= 1; i--)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
}

void main(void) {
    int a[N+1] = { 0 };
    readlong(a);
    writelong(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (i = 1; i < a[0]; i++)
> ```

```
for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++)
```

> ```
> a[a[0] - i + 1] = s[k] - '0';
> ```

```
a[a[0] - i + 1] = s[i] - '0';
```

А переменную `k` вообще убрать.